# Error: could not find function "nnn.R"

Tags: r

I sourced my function `nnn.R` using the line :

> source("nnn.R")*

and did not get any errors, but when I try to run it, this is what I get:

> Error: could not find function "nnn"*

[image]

this all what the function has inside

*function (x) is.null(x)*

Comment: nnn is a file, not a function. You need to create a function inside the "nnn.r" file to use it: `myfun <- function(x){doin' stuff with x}` The `source` command just reads in the lines you have written elsewhere; it doesn't work like MATLAB. You might want to scan the introduction to R, in particular this part: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Writing-your-own-functions

Comment: Oh I got it, this worked 
nnn <- function (x) {is.null(x)}

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nnn.R` is a file, not a function. The file must contain a function, defined as:

```
nnn <- function(x) {
  return (is.null(x))
}
```

Note that `nnn.R` may contain several function definitions. See for instance [this tutorial](http://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html).

Comment: Although the function definition given here would probably not be what you would want.